# Uber deep-linking not working from website

Tags: deep-linking, uber-api

I'm working on a map web app, which offers the possibility to go to a POI using Uber when the user is on a mobile device.
I'm trying to make the deep-linking API working, but actually it does not most of the time, and does sometimes (don't know why...).

- I first tried using the "universal deep-linking" format, which starts with `m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup`... But on my iPhone, it sent me to the appStore instead of starting the Uber application.
- Now I'm using the "native deep-linking" format, which starts with `uber://?action=setPickup&`....
  The Uber application is started, but after that, nothing happen... It worked one time, but when I retried... nothing. I'm on the map, centered on my location, and a text input invite me to write where I want to go.

Here an example of the URL that I use: `uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&pickup=my_location&dropoff[formatted_address]=Arch%C3%A9a%2C%20mus%C3%A9e%20d'arch%C3%A9ologie%20en%20pays%20de%20France&dropoff[latitude]=49.041019&dropoff[longitude]=2.507384`

Comment: The following should consistently work: https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=xxx&pickup=my_location&dropoff[formatted_address]=Uber%20HQ%2C%20Market%20Street%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2C%20United%20States&dropoff[latitude]=37.775231&dropoff[longitude]=-122.417528

Can you verify the special characters in the formatted address are url encoded? I think in your case the " 'arch" is causing an issue.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the url you gave does not work for me.

I tried both [unversal format](https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=xxx&pickup=my_location&dropoff[formatted_address]=Uber%20HQ%2C%20Market%20Street%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2C%20United%20States&dropoff[latitude]=37.775231&dropoff[longitude]=-122.417528)

and

**native format** `uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=xxx&pickup=my_location&dropoff[formatted_address]=Uber%20HQ%2C%20Market%20Street%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2C%20United%20States&dropoff[latitude]=37.775231&dropoff[longitude]=-122.417528`

Comment: Can you share the app version you are using and provide more detail to how you are testing?